# Error 500 on create table using Google API PHP client 1.0 fusion tables insert method

Tags: php, google-fusion-tables, google-api-php-client

This code should add a new table on an authenticated client:

```
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setClientId($config['client_id']);
$client->setClientSecret($config['client_secret']);
$client->setRedirectUri($config['redirect_uri']);
$client->setScopes(
    array(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login', 
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables'
    )
);
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

$fusionTablesService = new Google_Service_Fusiontables($client);

$table = new Google_Service_Fusiontables_Table();
$table->setName('testTable');

$column = new Google_Service_Fusiontables_Column();
$column->setName('testColumn');
$column->setType('STRING');

$table->setColumns(array($column));

$fusionTablesService->table->insert($table);
```

But it doesn't. I just get a 500 error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' 

with message 

'Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/tables: 
(500) Backend Error' 

in 

/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 79
```

which I can trace back to the last line: `$fusionTablesService->table->insert($table);`

I've been researching and trying for 6 hours, but the docs just suck.

Does anybody know what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that all I had to do was to set `isExportable` to `true` (`$table->setIsExportable('true');`). Here's the code working:

```
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setClientId($config['client_id']);
$client->setClientSecret($config['client_secret']);
$client->setRedirectUri($config['redirect_uri']);
$client->setScopes(
    array(
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login', 
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables'
    )
);
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

$fusionTablesService = new Google_Service_Fusiontables($client);

$table = new Google_Service_Fusiontables_Table();

$table->setName('testTable');

//missing line that was causing the trouble
$table->setIsExportable('true');

$column = new Google_Service_Fusiontables_Column();
$column->setName('testColumn');
$column->setType('STRING');

$table->setColumns(array($column));

$fusionTablesService->table->insert($table);
```